# Compilation errors with Gradle, Android Studio and Butterknife

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, butterknife

I've imported Eclipse Android project to Android Studio and it fails to compile with following errors:

```
Error:(7, 8) error: duplicate class: com.company.fragment.PrimaryFragment$$ViewInjector
```

I've tried adding apt plugin:

```
   apply plugin: 'android'
    apply plugin: 'apt'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

        defaultConfig {

            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }

        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        }
    }


dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.1"
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.1'

}
```

I think that this has something to do with *Butterknife*. But when I make a clean project with it, everything is ok.

Answer (score 3):

If you still have the target/build folders from eclipse in your build directory it might be a good idea to delete those.

Also Cleaning project under Project -> Clean might help.

Also if you are running maven or gradle from command line, it would be wise to run:

```
maven clean
```

or

```
gradle clean
```

Comment: Why the down vote. Even though @JakeWharton's answer is better and more explanatory, why down-vote?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need both the `apt` and the `compile` dependency, only the `compile` dependency.

By having it twice, the annotation processor is running twice (with two different output directories) which means the generated classes are created twice. The error you are seeing is because there are two identical classes being generated for your `PrimaryFragment`.

The `apt` scope (and plugin) are only needed for libraries which separate their runtimes from their annotation processors (sometimes called compilers). An example of this would be Dagger which has a `dagger` and `dagger-compiler`.

Comment: I'm not even using *apply plugin: 'apt'* but still I'm getting duplicate class issue.

Comment: This will change with ButterKnife 8 +, it will split annotation processor and runtime artifacts, which is cleaner. At that point, you can use apt scope for the annotation processor, though provided should also work (apt scope is only interesting to call generated code indeed).